# Is this data duplication when two exact pieces of data have different lifespans?

Tags: database-design, duplication

In my system, user has many bank accounts stored in `bank_accounts` table. Each bank account has a `currency` column. Now, users can receive payments to those bank accounts, stored in `payments` table. So, each payment is related to one row in `bank_account` table. In addition to `bank_account_id`, each row in `payments` table also has `amount` and `currency` columns. As you can see, the `currency` column on `payments` table causes data duplication, because the currency could always be derived from the related bank account. However, I'm afraid that in the future a bank account may be deleted from the system but the related payments will have to stay. Is it a valid argument to conclude that I don't have duplicated data in my schema?

Comment: Doesn't sound like duplication to me. In fact, if the bank receives payments in different currencies, and then has to convert to the currency of the target account, keeping those conversion details is an important piece of information about the payment.

Comment: In my system the given bank account only receives payments in its own currency. It is the very sense of the service, to provide many accounts in different currencies to avoid currency exchange provisions.

Comment: In that case it might be considered redundant data, unless a bank account record can be deleted, or unless a bank account currency type can be changed. But I try to treat normalization rules as a guide, not a law. I can see leaving the second record for the purpose of validation checks or auditing, for the purpose of having a more explicit transaction history, for performance purposes in queries, etc.

Comment: I think you cold post the latter of your comments as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization rules are a useful guideline, not a strict law.

Even if you don't anticipate the `currency` field in the `payments` table to ever be different than the `currency` field for the related `bank_account`, I can think of any number of reasons to keep both:

- What if the account record is ever deleted? (Accidentally or deliberately)
- What if the account record changes currency type?
- The field could be used as a point of immediate validation before committing the payment
- The field could be used after the fact as an integrity/validation audit
- It could improve performance for certain queries instead of requiring a join to the `bank_accounts` table.

Comment: I also liked your remark in the comment below my question that it allows for more explicit transaction history.